# Is it possible to stop streaming jobs without lose the current data?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming pipeline that reads from a PubSub subscription. The pipeline applies 1 hour's fixed windows and after doing some transforms, such as GroupByKey,  writes the data to BigQuery.

My problem is that if I stop the job execution, the data of the current window are not written to BigQuery and these are lost since neither are in the subscription nor written in BigQuery.

Comment: Marcos - do you want to reload your pipeline with a new version of your code? Or do you want to drain out the pipeline and then stop it permanently.

Comment: Reuven - I want to reload my pipeline with a new version of my code without data loss.

Answer (score 2):

Marcos,

The update feature is now live in Maven. It requires that you run a new compatible pipeline with the same value for jobName and the --update flag. Note however that if you change your code too much (this usually involves removing or changing GroupByKey or other combining operations) --update will fail, since the service won't know how to associate the old state with the new pipeline.

Comment: You can find documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline)

Answer (score 1):

A feature to update a running Dataflow pipeline is in the works. In fact, a version of it is already committed to our GitHub repository and should be a part the next release to Maven Central. Please follow [our Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/java) for the specific version information.

The update functionality is triggered via the `--update` pipeline option. See [DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java) for more details.

Comment: Davor - It's a really useful feature for update dataflow pipelines. Thanks!. But if at some moment I need to stop the pipeline during e.g. an hour, Is it possible to stop streaming jobs without lose the current data of the window of that hour?

Comment: A this time, `update` is the only feature that we have in this space. Perhaps you can try updating the pipeline. The updated pipeline may, for example, have a future window hardcoded and store data from that window in a file on GCS to avoid data-loss.